# Crystal Reports XI R2 runtime on Windows 7 x64

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using Crystal Reports **XI R2 (11.5.3300.0)** in existing (32 bits) applications. We are in the process of upgrading to Windows7 64 bits.

During our compatibility tests, we bump into an issue indicating the crystal reports runtime is not available. I'm leaving out the exception detail here, as it is in Dutch, but basically it is saying that the runtime is not installed correctly, and that I should install the distributable CRRedist*.msi.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find that distributable. When I check on the support site, https://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567, it refers to a bootstrapper in the Program Files folder. However, the indicated subfolder does not exist.

Anyone who has bumped into the same type of problems *for this version of Crystal Reports* (I'm aware of the fact that several versions have been released after this one)? Where can I find the redistributable?

Mind that our applications are compiled for x86, so I think that the x86 runtime should do the trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just a quick caveat to any answer for you, if performance is important you should know that the x86 dlls will be significantly slower under emulation in an x64 o/s

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it was something I ran into as well so I wanted to update it with my experience.

I was not able to locate a redistributable for 64 bit.  Instead, I had to change the project I was compiling to target x86.  By default the C# and VB projects have the property settings on the project set to AnyCPU.  Change it to x86 and this problem goes away.

For VB.NET, right click on project and select properties, go to the compile tab.  On VS 2012, you will find it on the Target CPU combo box on that screen.  On VS 2008, you need to select "Advanced Compile Options..." and then you will find the Target CPU combo box.

For C#, right click on project and select properties, go to the Build tab and you will find it as "Platform target:" combo box.