# Crystal report compatible with windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, crystal-reports

i am having a application made in visual studio 2005 which uses crystal report version 10.2.3600.0 . i am using CRRedist2005_x86.msi... it works fine on all xp machines... but does not work on windows 7 64 bit machine...

Can u assist me which crystal report viewer is compatible with windows 7 64 bit

[Additional information added from subsequent question:]

on my client machine it throws the following error

An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required. Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information. "

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17325893/382424) to a similar question for the answer.