# crystal report v10.2.3600.0 runtime for windows 7 64 bit

Tags: crystal-reports, windows-7-x64

can u please suggest a  crystal report runtime 10.2.3600.0 version download supported by windows 7 64 bit...

on my client machine it throws the following error

An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information. "

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crystal report compatible with windows 7 64 bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006067/crystal-report-compatible-with-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

```
(C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\CrystalReports\CRRedist2005_x86.msi)
```

please install this setup in your windows 7 64 bit pc and try to open your reports.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at

http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567
or
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.